# log4j2にアップデートするとeclipseのコンソールにエラーログが表示されてしまう

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, struts

Struts2フレームワークを利用したWebアプリケーションにてStruts2.3→Struts2.5へバージョンアップ（同時にlog4j→log4j2）後、eclipse（mavenプロジェクト）でデバッグ実行（tomcat起動）したところ、コンソールに下記エラーが出てました。
log4j2.xmlの記述も問題ないと思いますが、エラーが消えません。
ちなみにlog4j2.xmlで指定したファイルのログは書き出されております。
エラー内容について何かご存知であればお教え頂けますか？

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
```

実行環境は下記の通りです。
【実行環境】
・eclipse luna 4.4.2
・CentOS7.3
・Apache2.4.6
・Tomcat7.0.69
・Java1.8.0_131
・Struts2.5.10.1
・Spring4.1.6

log4j2は下記ライブラリを使用しております。
・log4j-core-2.7.jar
・log4j-api-2.7.jar
・log4j-web-2.7.jar
・log4j-1.2-api-2.7.jar

log4j2.xmlは下記の通りです。
【log4j2.xml】

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="off">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %t %m (%F:%L) \r\n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="AAA_LOG"
        fileName="/var/log/AAA.log"
        filePattern="/var/log/AAA.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %t %m \r\n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnstartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />   
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="BBB_LOG"
        fileName="/var/log/BBB.log"
        filePattern="/var/log/BBB.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %t %m \r\n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnstartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />   
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
    </RollingFile>        
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="XXX.YYY.ZZZ" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="AAA_LOG"/>
    </Logger>        
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="BBB_LOG"/>
    </Root>        
</Loggers>
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/127895

Comment: 「`ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found.`」と出力されているので、作成した`log4j2.xml`を読み込んでなさそうですね。Javaオプション`-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///path/to/your/log4j2.xml`を追加してみたら、どうなりますか？

Comment: log4j2.xmlは情報元（https://qiita.com/pica/items/afcebf0a06a745cb8c8c）を元にweb.xmlにファイルパスを（※１）のように設定しておりますが、エラーは消えない状態です。（※１）<context-param><param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name><param-value>/path/to/your/log4j2.xml</context-param>

Comment: そのパスにファイルがないということはないですか？[公式ガイド](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html)に、Log4J2の設定ファイルの参照の仕方が記載されています。そのとおりのパスにファイルはありますか？

Comment: web.xmlに指定したパスにはlog4j2.xmlが存在します。またweb.xmlのlog4jConfigurationに存在しないファイル（例えばlog4j3.xml）を指定すると、eclipseのコンソールには「ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.」以外に追加エラー「ERROR StatusLogger File not found in file system or classspath: /path/to/your/log4j3.xml」が表示されます。log4j2.xml内で指定したログは出力できているので、log4j2.xml自体は認識しているように思うのですが、「ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.」が表示される原因がわかりません。

Comment: @hirohiro0369 なるほど。ファイルを読み込んでいるのであれば、`log4j2.xml`の`<Configuration status="off">`の行を`<Configuration status="debug">`などに変更すると、何か分かるかもしれないですね。

Comment: 回答が遅くなりました。<Configuration status="debug">に変更しましたが、log4j2エラーの原因となるような情報は見つかりませんでした。

Comment: @hirohiro0369 `log4j2.xml`をよくよく見ると、最後に`</Configuration>`が無いですね。それに起因しているかもしれませんね。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。log4j2.xmlに</Configuration>を追加しましたが、エラーは未だ消えない状況です。